# Given $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{2}{k}$ where $a$ and $b$ are variables. Maximise, $\frac{1}{a+n}+\frac{1}{b+n}$ where $n\in \Bbb{Z}, n>0$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{2}{k}$ where $a$ and $b$ are variables. Maximise, $\frac{1}{a+n}+\frac{1}{b+n}$ where $n\in \Bbb{Z}, n>0$.

Prove: I think the maximum is when $\frac{1}{a}=\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{k}.$

So that would give $\frac{1}{a+n}+\frac{1}{b+n}=\boxed{\frac{2}{k+n}}$.

And since $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{2}{k}$ is fixed, we get that $\frac{a+b}{ab}=\frac{2}{k}.$

Moreover, we get that the Harmonic mean is fixed which is $$
\frac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}=\frac{2}{\frac{2}{k}}=k.$$

And we get that $\frac{1}{ab}\ge \frac{1}{k^2}.$

Comment: Any restrictions on $a,b,k$? e.g., are they required to be positive integers?

Comment: You've had a comment, and five answers (!!), and you haven't had a word to say about any of them, Raheel. People are trying to help you. It's extremely rude to ignore them all.

Comment: Sorry @GerryMyerson I just didn't open MSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that you have an equality constraint to elimintae $b$ from the problem$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{2}{k} \implies b=\frac{a k}{2 a-k}$$
$$f(a)=\frac{1}{a+n}+\frac{1}{b+n}=\frac{2 a-k}{a k+2 a n-k n}+\frac{1}{a+n}$$
$$f'(a)=\frac{k^2}{(k n-a (k+2 n))^2}-\frac{1}{(a+n)^2}$$ that is to say
$$k^2(a+n)^2=(k n-a (k+2 n))^2$$ Croos multiply to get
$$4 a^2 n (k+n)-4 a k n (k+n)=4 a n (a-k) (k+n)=0 \implies a=b=k$$

So $$f(k)=\frac{2}{k+n}$$ Now, the second derivative test
$$f''(a)=\frac{2}{(a+n)^3}-\frac{2 k^2 (-k-2 n)}{(k n-a (k+2 n))^3}$$
$$f''(k)=-\frac{4 n}{k (k+n)^3}$$ If this is negative, then $\frac{2}{k+n}$ is a maximum value.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of using calculus but then didn't have enough tools! Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using multivariable calculus**

Let $f(a,b)=\frac{1}{a+n}+\frac {1}{b+n}$. Using Lagrange multipliers, at an extremum of $f$ under the constraint, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}(a,b)=-\frac{1}{(a+n)^2}=-\frac{\lambda}{a^2} \text { and } \frac{\partial f}{\partial b}(a,b)=-\frac{1}{(b+n)^2}=-\frac{\lambda}{b^2}$$
Thus $$\frac{a^2}{(a+n)^2}=\frac{b^2}{(b+n)^2}=\lambda\tag{1}$$
For any $n$, the function $x\mapsto \frac{x}{x+n}$ is easily shown to be injective. Thus equation $(1)$ is only possible if $a=b$.

Consequently, any extremum is at $a=b=\frac 1 k$. To verify that the extremum is indeed a maximum, we compute the Hessian of the Lagrangian:
$$\left ( 
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{2}{(a+n)^3} -\frac{2\lambda }{a^3} &0\\
0 & \frac{2}{(b+n)^3} -\frac{2\lambda }{b^3}
\end{array}
\right)=\left ( 
\begin{array}{cc}
-\frac{2n}{a^3(a+n)^3} &0\\
0 & -\frac{2n}{b^3(b+n)^3}
\end{array}
\right)$$
which, since $n>0$, is clearly negative, semi-definite.
Consequently,
$$\boxed{\text{The maximum is }\frac{2}{k+n}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(a,b) = \dfrac{1}{a+n}+\dfrac{1}{b+n} = \dfrac{a+b+2n}{ab+n(a+b)+n^2}$. Substituting $\dfrac{2ab}{k}$ for $(a+b)$ into the equation yields: $f(a,b) = \dfrac{2ab+2nk}{n^2k+(2n+k)ab} = \dfrac{2x+2nk}{(2n+k)x+n^2k}, x = ab$. Observe that $\dfrac{4(ab)^2}{k^2} = \left(\dfrac{2ab}{k}\right)^2 = (a+b)^2 \ge 4ab\implies x = ab \ge k^2$. Thus the problem reduces to finding the maximum value of $g(x) = \dfrac{2x+2nk}{(2n+k)x+n^2k}$ over $[k^2,\infty)$. Taking derivative $g'(x) = \dfrac{-2n^2k-2nk^2}{((2n+k)x+nk^2)^2}< 0$. So $g$ decreases and $g_{\text{max}} = g(k^2) = \dfrac{2k^2+2nk}{(2n+k)k^2+n^2k}=\dfrac{2k+2n}{(2n+k)k+n^2}= \dfrac{2(n+k)}{(n+k)^2}= \dfrac{2}{n+k}$. This max value occurs when $a = b = k$.

Answer (score 1):

Without calculus, use $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{2}{k}$ to eliminate $ab$ from $$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a+n}+\frac{1}{b+n}}=\frac{ab+nu+n^2}{u+2n},$$ where $u=a+b$, and split the numerator to get $$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a+n}+\frac{1}{b+n}}=\frac{2n+k}{2}-\frac{n(n+k)}{u+2n}.$$ Then to maximise $\frac{1}{a+n}+\frac{1}{b+n}$ you need to minimise $u$, which can be done by considering the AM-GM inequality $u^2 \geq 4ab = 2ku$, giving the minimum $u$ when $a=b$ and $u = 2k$, as required.

I would add that I have assumed $a$ and $b$ need to be positive. If this isn't the case, let $a=-n+\epsilon$, where $n>\epsilon >0$, and $b=\Big(2k+\frac{1}{n-\epsilon}\Big)^{-1}$ (which is positive); then $\frac{1}{a+n}+\frac{1}{b+n}=\frac{1}{\epsilon} +\frac{1}{b+n}$ is as large as you like, for small enough $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming that $a$ and $b$ are positive.) The function
$$
 f(t) = \frac{1}{1/t+n}
$$
is *strictly concave* on $(0, \infty)$. It follows that
$$
 \frac{1}{a+n}+\frac{1}{b+n} = f\left( \frac 1a \right)+f\left( \frac 1b \right) \le 2 f\left( \frac {1/a+1/b}{2} \right) = 2f\left( \frac 1k \right) = \frac{2}{k+n} \, .
$$
Equality holds exactly if $1/a=1/b$, i.e. if $a=b=k$.

---

Alternatively:
$$
\frac{1}{a+n}+\frac{1}{b+n} - \frac{2}{k+n} 
= \frac{1}{a+n}+\frac{1}{b+n} - \frac{2}{\frac{2}{1/a+1/b}+n} \\
= \frac{1}{a+n}+\frac{1}{b+n} - \frac{2(a+b)}{2ab+n(a+b)} \\
= - \frac{n(a-b)^2}{(a+n)(b+n)(2ab+n(a+b))} \le 0
$$
with equality exactly if $a=b$.